# How to format a US currency string using python or sed

Tags: bash, shell, python-2.7, sed, scripting

I have numerous invoices that I sent to clients with this string at the bottom:
`Total: 1,000.00`
or whatever the amount. Some are 2 figures, some 5 figures + the decimal part.

The thing is that the number's format is inconsistant accross all invoices. Sometimes its `1.000,00` and it keeps on switching the dot and the coma.

so with grep, awk and sed, i am able to only get the amount part from all invoices, without the dollar sign in order to sum them up to a grand total. But the dot and coma switching confuses python, obviously.

So in python (could be in sed as well), i am looking to convert the third char from the right to a dot and then from there on, every fourth char it finds, convert it to a coma.

In other words, it has to be able to separate the digits in groups of 3 from the right, add a coma in between each of them except for the first group at the far right which would be 2 digits separated by a dot.

Hope that is clear enough...

Comment: Why don't you simply strip all punctuation and divide by 100?

Comment: @tripleee because i need the currency format.

Comment: Once you have parsed it into a number  you can format it any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourstring = yourstring[:(len(yourstring)-3)].replace(".",",") + "." + yourstring[-2:]
```

I tried this on python and I think that works.

Comment: In fact, it worked perfectly. But if I wanted to replace all spaces by a coma (like that number 1 334 344.34), how would you modify your command?

Comment: It's only other replace: `yourstring = yourstring[:(len(yourstring)-3)].replace(".",",").replace(" ",",") + "." + yourstring[-2:]` but this comment will replace all the spaces in your string. As an example, if you have the string `Total: 1,000.00`, It'll be replaced by `Total:,1,000.00`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/$/ /
:coma
     s/\([0-9]\)[.]\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/g;t coma
:dot
     s/\([0-9]\),\([0-9][0-9][^0-9]\)/\1.\2/g;t dot
     s/ $//
     ' YourFile
```

- use general and recursive modification for all number on each line.
- change every dot number into coma structure then change last coma to a dot
- need a trick to change number at end of string (add a space at start, remove it at the end [this could be optimized with a previous test])
- posix compliant

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way i've found to handle this is using a bit of sed, some bash and for the final print, `printf`, which allow us easy currency formatting with `"%'.2f"` (note the `'` character, it is mandatory):

```
# Get rid of every character that is not a digit
totals=$( echo "$totals" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' )

# Sum up the amounts
sum=0
for n in $totals; do
    sum=$(($sum+$n))
done

# Put back the comas at each thousand, the dot at decimals and the $ sign in
sansdec=(${#sum}-2)
sum="${sum:0:$sansdec}.${sum: -2}"
printf "%s" "\$"
printf "%'.2f\n" "$sum"
```